# What is (\d+)/(\d+) in regex?

Tags: regex

I know it's a Regular Expression. I have seen this particular regular expression in a piece of code. What does it do? Thanks

Comment: http://www.regex101.com/r/eC8eU4

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Expanding on minitech's answer:

- `(` start a capture group
- `\d` a [shorthand character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html), which matches all numbers; it is the same as `[0-9]`
- `+` one or more of the expression
- `)` end a capture group
- `/` a literal forward slash

Here is an example:

```
>>> import re
>>> exp = re.compile('(\d+)/(\d+)')
>>> foo = re.match(exp,'1234/5678')
>>> foo.groups()
('1234', '5678')
```

If you remove the brackets `()`, the expression will still match, but you'll only capture one set:

```
>>> foo = re.match('\d+/(\d+)','1234/5678')
>>> foo.groups()
('5678',)
```

Answer (score 11):

It matches one or more digits followed by a slash followed by one or more digits.

The two "one or more digits" here also form groups, which can be extracted and used.